# Rendering loop error with react axios setState

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate

I have different ingredients(vodka, gin, whiskey...) json files in a dummy folder.
I have an IngredientList.js where I select one ingredient and pass it down to
IngredientSearch.js

The IngredientSearch.js gets the relevant json file based on the ingredient name and then I set the state of ingredientRes to the res.data.drinks

Problem I am getting is that when I print the console.log(newVals) --> the console logs the arrays from the json **infinitely**. Seems like I am rerendering something infinitely.

What is wrong with my setup?

IngredientSearch.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class IngredientSearch extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            ingredientRes: []
        };
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        let ingredient = this.props.ingredient;  //for example: vodka
        this.getIngredient_drinks(ingredient);
    }
    getIngredient_drinks = (ingredient) => {
        if(ingredient !== null) {
            axios.get(`../dummy/${ingredient}.json`)
                .then((res)=>{
                    let newVals = [];
                    newVals.push(res.data.drinks);
                    //console.log(newVals); // keeps relogging the arrays
                    this.setState({ ingredientRes: newVals });
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }
    }
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                IngredientSearch Results
                I want to map the ingredientRes here
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default IngredientSearch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like -

```
if (this.props.ingredient !== prevProps.ingredient) {
    this.getIngredient_drinks(ingredient);
  }
```

Otherwise it will cause an infinite loop.

For reference - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate